# Logstash : Split json object

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, split, logstash

Please I have a json Object which results from an xml input, it looks like this :

```
{
  "@version" => "1",
"@timestamp" => "2016-04-11T15:35:07.372Z",
      "host" => "YUSUF-PC",
   "command" => "nana",
       "doc" => {
    "TotalResults" => "1892",
           "Audit" => [
        [0] {
                    "Id" => "2260167",
                "Action" => "UPDATE",
              "ParentId" => "30612",
            "ParentType" => "defect",
                  "Time" => "2016-01-04 08:27:59",
                  "User" => "nana",
            "Properties" => {
                "Property" => [
                    [0] {
                           "Label" => "Statut",
                            "Name" => "status",
                        "NewValue" => [
                            [0] "En cours"
                        ]
                    },
                    [1] {
                           "Label" => "Affecté à",
                            "Name" => "owner",
                        "NewValue" => [
                            [0] "nana"
                        ]
                    },
                    [2] {
                           "Label" => "Priorité",
                            "Name" => "severity",
                        "NewValue" => [
                            [0] "nana"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        [1] {
                    "Id" => "2260168",
                "Action" => "UPDATE",
              "ParentId" => "30612",
            "ParentType" => "defect",
                  "Time" => "2016-01-04 09:45:33",
                  "User" => "nana",
            "Properties" => {
                "Property" => [
                    [0] {
                           "Label" => "Affecté à",
                            "Name" => "owner",
                        "NewValue" => [
                            [0] "nana"
                        ],
                        "OldValue" => [
                            [0] "nana"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
} }
```

I need to split this json to properties, ie to get each document containing one property, the problem is not the split operation, but when I insert this to elasticsearch, the "NewValue" field doesn't get into account... So I need to write a ruby filter to alter the value to value[0]. Anyone can help, I'm not good at ruby ?

I want to get a json like this one :

```
{
  "@version" => "1",
"@timestamp" => "2016-04-11T15:35:07.372Z",
      "host" => "YUSUF-PC",
   "command" => "nana",
       "doc" => {
    "TotalResults" => "1892",
           "Audit" => [
        [0] {
                    "Id" => "2260167",
                "Action" => "UPDATE",
              "ParentId" => "30612",
            "ParentType" => "defect",
                  "Time" => "2016-01-04 08:27:59",
                  "User" => "nana",
            "Properties" => {
                "Property" => 
                    {
                           "Label" => "Statut",
                            "Name" => "status",
                        "NewValue" => "En cours"
                        }                            
                    }
                }

             ]
         }
       }
```

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" including the final links, and "[mcve]". We'd like to see your effort toward solving this, either as the minimum code you've written, or where you searched and why those pages didn't help. Right now it looks like you want us to write it for you. Also, your "sample" JSON isn't JSON, it's a Ruby hash that looks like it came from IRB.

Comment: I don't want you to write it for me, I tried my best dude but I'm not expert at ruby, the JSON mentionned before is a result of logstash input, the logstash tag is very clear. That's rude @theTinMan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps.

```
old = {
"@version" => "1",
"@timestamp" => "2016-04-11T15:35:07.372Z",
  "host" => "YUSUF-PC",
   "command" => "nana",
   "doc" => {
     "TotalResults" => "1892",
       "Audit" => [
       {
                "Id" => "2260167",
                "Action" => "UPDATE",
                "ParentId" => "30612",
                "ParentType" => "defect",
                "Time" => "2016-01-04 08:27:59",
                "User" => "nana",
                "Properties" => {
                  "Property" => [
                 {
                       "Label" => "Statut",
                       "Name" => "status",
                       "NewValue" => [
                        "En cours"
                    ]
                },
                 {
                       "Label" => "Affecté à",
                        "Name" => "owner",
                    "NewValue" => [
                         "nana"
                    ]
                },
                 {
                       "Label" => "Priorité",
                        "Name" => "severity",
                    "NewValue" => [
                         "nana"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
     {
                "Id" => "2260168",
            "Action" => "UPDATE",
          "ParentId" => "30612",
        "ParentType" => "defect",
              "Time" => "2016-01-04 09:45:33",
              "User" => "nana",
        "Properties" => {
            "Property" => [
                 {
                       "Label" => "Affecté à",
                        "Name" => "owner",
                    "NewValue" => [
                         "nana"
                    ],
                    "OldValue" => [
                         "nana"
                    ]
                }
            ]
          }
      }
  ]
  } }

  ##THIS IS THE LINE ACTUALLY DOING WORK.
  old["doc"]["Audit"].map{|prop| prop["Properties"]["Property"].map{|value| value['NewValue']= value['NewValue'].first} }
  old
  => {"@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2016-04-11T15:35:07.372Z", "host"=>"YUSUF-PC", "command"=>"nana", "doc"=>{"TotalResults"=>"1892", "Audit"=>[{"Id"=>"2260167", "Action"=>"UPDATE", "ParentId"=>"30612", "ParentType"=>"defect", "Time"=>"2016-01-04 08:27:59", "User"=>"nana", "Properties"=>{"Property"=>[{"Label"=>"Statut", "Name"=>"status", "NewValue"=>"En cours"}, {"Label"=>"Affecté à", "Name"=>"owner", "NewValue"=>"nana"}, {"Label"=>"Priorité", "Name"=>"severity", "NewValue"=>"nana"}]}}, {"Id"=>"2260168", "Action"=>"UPDATE", "ParentId"=>"30612", "ParentType"=>"defect", "Time"=>"2016-01-04 09:45:33", "User"=>"nana", "Properties"=>{"Property"=>[{"Label"=>"Affecté à", "Name"=>"owner", "NewValue"=>"nana", "OldValue"=>["nana"]}]}}]}}
```